# DLL looking for wrong version

Tags: c#, dll

I have developed a class library (dll) that uses WinSCPnet.dll in Visual Studio 2015. While troubleshooting why it was looking for the wrong dll, I added the Nuget for it, getting the most recent version. The version we are using is actually a few before that, so I uninstalled the latest (using Nuget) and installed the version I want. Now, when it runs, it is looking for the newest version.

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'WinSCPnet, Version=1.6.5.9925, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=2271ec4a3c56d0bf' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I have tried searching the registry, gacutil /u (which ran successfully and removed the dll but I still get this message), cleaned the project and rebuilt, deleted everything in bin and obj and rebuilt - what am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a config file which contains binding redirects?

Comment: @ColinM no I don't

Comment: Did you check your web/app config?  The <runtime> -> <assemblyBinding> section may have the incorrect version in a <bindingRedirect>.

Comment: @ap.dev no - it's not a web app, it's a class library (dll) I've created. Updated description to clarify that. If there is something like this in this project, I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: @HansPassant fuslogvw is showing me some things that are going on with MSBuild for a database project, but it shows me nothing for this project. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Unload your project , right click, edit .csproj file .. find your reference , it's gone be something like this `<Reference Include="WinSCPnet, Version=1.6.5.9925 .../>"`, edit that  create open close Reference tag `<Reference></Reference>`
Inside put `<HintPath>path to your dll file here</HintPath>`

Hope this helps!?

Comment: I have the following in the .csproj file. It already shows the correct version that I want it to use. Is this what you were talking about editing?

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="WinSCPnet, Version=1.3.5.6958, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2271ec4a3c56d0bf, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\WinSCP.5.9.2\lib\WinSCPnet.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: Yes, but your hint path version is diferent than version in reference , as you can see .. go to your packages and see how many version you have... try changing path

Comment: I see what you mean, but the WinSCPnet.dll has version 1.3.5.6958 but the exe version for it is 5.9.2. I don't know why they do this to me, but it's very confusing. So, they are actually the same version and the version I want to be using.

Comment: It's not just you , had same problem few months ago on one big project... so we decided to just download references via Nugget, the delete them, then add references by our self to avoid this kind of confusion.

Comment: So you got, for example, Winscp through nuget, had it install. Then, uninstalled? Then what did you do? (Maybe this is what I need to do. It sounds similar to what I've tried but maybe not exactly how you did it.)

Comment: Kinda like that, install it from nugget, go to packages folder, copy them to other location, uninstall them , the add reference for them via 'add reference' .. this way i can easy control version of my dll, and if i need to upgrade i just change path and version by hand!

Comment: Ah, okay - I tried that, too. It still is looking for the wrong version. And anywhere where I try to use the dll in another app, it is also looking for the wrong version. It's like something is crossed up in my computer, but I can't figure out what. I am pointing specifically at what I want, but it is still looking for the wrong thing.